# Inserting new data into xml from datatable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an xml file about 900MB and i want to insert data from datatable to that existing xml.

There is a way to do this by using load and save like below;

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
var root = xdoc.Descendants("DocumentElement").FirstOrDefault()
if (root != null){
    root.Add(new XElement("tag", "value"));
    xdoc.Save(FilePath);
}
```

However, its cost too much. Loading 900MB xml into datatable can cause memory exceptions and poor performance for couple of new rows.

How can i add new rows to big existing xml from datatable?

Answer (score 0):

`XDocument` (and `XmlDocument` as well) loads whole file into memory. You should use [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) with combination of [XNode.WriteTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Example from `XNode.WriteTo` documentation:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
xws.Indent = true;

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws)) 
{
   XElement child2 = new XElement("AnotherChild",
    new XElement("GrandChild", "different content"));
   child2.WriteTo(xw);
   xw.WriteEndElement();
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

You can read big xml documents in the same way, check example in [XNode.ReadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx) documentation